# animate rest ng-repeat element when a child is removed

Tags: angularjs, css

I am removing an element in ng-repeat using javascript splice method ..elements of my ng-repeat are in two rows not in list styles ...now i need to apply a animation on the rest of element(not on the element being removed. when rest of element re adjust them..according to their position ...mainly i need to show the animation when they move from one place to another .

Comment: Please correct sentences, I am unable to understand. Also provide code for exact and quick answers. From what I understood, you can use `ng-class` in this case

Comment: i updated the question .. also i need to apply the animation how code will help